# Conjecture about essential singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the following true?

Suppose $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z_0$. Then $f$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$ if and only if $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} |(z-z_0)^k f(z)| = \infty$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

The backward direction is true, but I think the forward direction is false. Is there a counterexample?

Edit: I meant to say that the backwards direction is true, not the forwards direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, neither direction is true. Having an essential singularity at $z_0$ is equivalent to $f$ being given as a Laurent series near $z_0$, i.e.
$$f(z) = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n (z-z_0)^n,$$
so that for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists a $k\geq N$, so that $a_{-k}\neq 0$. So, multiplying this power series by any $(z-z_0)^k$ gets rid of some of the Laurent coefficients, but not all $-$ i.e. the remaining power series still has infinitely many coefficients of negative index and thus $\tilde f(z):= (z-z_0)^kf(z)$ still has an essential singularity at $z_0$. But this means that $\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow z_0} \tilde f(z)$ is not defined.

(In fact, for any $w\in\mathbb{C}$, you can find a sequence $(z_n)$ converging against $z_0$, so that $\tilde f(z_n)\rightarrow w$.)

However, you could rephrase your statement: $f$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$, if and only if $\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow z_0} (z-z_0)^kf(z)$ is undefined for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Or if you are only interested in the reverse direction: If for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ there exists a sequence $(z_n)$ converging against $z_0$, so that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} |(z-z_0)^kf(z_n)|=\infty$, then $f$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for the answer! It makes perfect sense. This essentially follows from the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: @cauchy_coffee Yes, exactly.

Comment: @FShrike No, in complex analysis this is not the case. Writing $\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow z_0}| f(z)| = \infty$ means that for all $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ that converges to $z_0$, one has $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} |f(z_n)| = \infty$. Not defined on the other hand means that there exist at least two sequences converging against $z_0$, so that $f$ converges against two different values along them.

Comment: @Nuke_Gunray Yeah, I realised my mistake. I was initially thinking your answer was wrong because I had always assumed to myself that something like: $$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(z-z_0)^{-n}$$Would satisfy: $$\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)^nf(z)=\infty$$For all $n\ge0$. I was unaware that this was a false belief ; )